# VS Code not running output on the debug console

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS Code. After some updates, it doesnt print an output on the debug console like it used to. It doesnt show any problems or mistakes, it just stays empty. I think it might be something related to Node.js, as it used to give me options when i run my code. Im always selecting Node.js, but that is not showing anymore. Im sorry if its a dumb questions, Im really new. Ill upload some screenshots, thank you in advance. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05uNG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8FSK.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wDZE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g2x4.png)

I tried changing some settings and restarting VS Code, but nothing worked.

Comment: how are you running the program? do you have a launch config? if so, show your launch config. add version info to the post for all your stuff too